# How to add several instances of UserControl from DLL into my WPF

Tags: wpf, dll, mvvm

I building a WPF app. WPF is pretty new for me so maybe it is a easy question :)

Catch is that I build DLL WPF library. Now I like to import UserControl from this dll into my app, several times (6 times more exactly).

WPF DLL library it is a Graph with points. Until now I import DLL UserControl, but show only ListBox (Graph) without points. Points are movable together with connectors (between points).

My App XAML:

```
<ScrollViewer>
    <Grid>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>


        <dr:UserControl1 Grid.Row="0" DataContext="{Binding UCData1, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        <dr:UserControl1 Grid.Row="1" DataContext="{Binding UCData2, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        <dr:UserControl1 Grid.Row="2" DataContext="{Binding UCData3, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        <dr:UserControl1 Grid.Row="3" DataContext="{Binding UCData4, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        <dr:UserControl1 Grid.Row="4" DataContext="{Binding UCData5, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        <dr:UserControl1 Grid.Row="5" DataContext="{Binding UCData6, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>

    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

My C# App:
{

```
    public MainWindow()
    {

        //InitializeComponent();

        UserControl1 UCData1 = new UserControl1();
        UserControl1 UCData2 = new UserControl1();
        UserControl1 UCData3 = new UserControl1();
        UserControl1 UCData4 = new UserControl1();
        UserControl1 UCData5 = new UserControl1();
        UserControl1 UCData6 = new UserControl1();




    }

    public object UCData1 { get; set; }
    public object UCData2 { get; set; }
    public object UCData3 { get; set; }
    public object UCData4 { get; set; }
    public object UCData5 { get; set; }
    public object UCData6 { get; set; }
}
```

UserControl XAML DLL:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVisibilityConverter"/>

        <CompositeCollection x:Key="Col">
            <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding DataContext.Connectors, Source={x:Reference view}}"/>
            <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding DataContext.Nodes, Source={x:Reference view}}"/>
        </CompositeCollection>

        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Node}">

            <Canvas Name="dragTarget">
                <Thumb DragDelta="Thumb_Drag" DragStarted="Thumb_DragStarted" DragCompleted="Thumb_DragCompleted">
                    <Thumb.Template>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Thumb">
                            <Canvas Margin="-10,-10,10,10">
                                <Ellipse Height="20" Width="20" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" Fill="Yellow"
                                         x:Name="Ellipse"/>
                                <TextBlock Canvas.Top="-20" Canvas.Left="-40" Width="100" 
                                           TextAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Name}" FontWeight="Bold"
                                           IsHitTestVisible="False"
                                           Visibility="{Binding DataContext.ShowNames, 
                                                                RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window},
                                                                Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}"/>

                                <TextBlock Canvas.Left="30" Canvas.Top="10"
                                           Text="{Binding X, StringFormat='{}X = {0}'}"
                                           IsHitTestVisible="False"
                                           Visibility="Collapsed" x:Name="XText"/>

                                <TextBlock Canvas.Left="30" Canvas.Top="25"
                                           Text="{Binding Y, StringFormat='{}Y = {0}'}"
                                           IsHitTestVisible="False"
                                           Visibility="Collapsed" x:Name="YText"/>
                            </Canvas>

                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>

                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}}" Value="True">
                                    <Setter TargetName="Ellipse" Property="Fill" Value="Red"/>
                                </DataTrigger>
                                <Trigger Property="IsDragging" Value="True">
                                    <Setter TargetName="Ellipse" Property="Fill" Value="Green"/>
                                </Trigger>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DataContext.ShowAllCoordinates, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}" Value="True">
                                    <Setter TargetName="XText" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                                    <Setter TargetName="YText" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                                </DataTrigger>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding 
                                    }" Value="True">
                                    <Setter TargetName="Ellipse" Property="StrokeThickness" Value="2"/>
                                    <Setter TargetName="Ellipse" Property="Stroke" Value="Red"/>
                                    <Setter TargetName="Ellipse" Property="Fill" Value="White"/>
                                </DataTrigger>
                                <MultiDataTrigger>
                                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                        <Condition Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}}" Value="True"/>
                                        <Condition Binding="{Binding DataContext.ShowCurrentCoordinates, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}" Value="True"/>
                                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Setter TargetName="XText" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                                    <Setter TargetName="YText" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                                </MultiDataTrigger>

                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>

                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Thumb.Template>
                </Thumb>
            </Canvas>

        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Connector}">
            <Line Stroke="Blue" StrokeThickness="3"
                        X1="{Binding Start.X}" Y1="{Binding Start.Y}"
                        X2="{Binding End.X}" Y2="{Binding End.Y}" x:Name="Line"/>
            <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding End}" Value="{x:Null}">
                    <Setter TargetName="Line" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}}" Value="True">
                    <Setter TargetName="Line" Property="Stroke" Value="Red"/>
                    <Setter TargetName="Line" Property="StrokeDashArray" Value="2 3"/>
                    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard x:Name="DashAnimation">
                            <Storyboard Duration="00:00:01" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                                <DoubleAnimation From="0" To="50" Storyboard.TargetName="Line" Storyboard.TargetProperty="StrokeDashOffset"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                        <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="DashAnimation"/>
                    </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                </DataTrigger>
            </DataTemplate.Triggers>

        </DataTemplate>

    </Grid.Resources>

    <Grid>

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Name="column1" Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Name="row1" Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Margin="2" x:Name="tbTitle" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" TextAlignment="Center" Text="XAL"/>
        <TextBlock Margin="2" x:Name="Time" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" TextAlignment="Center" Text="Time" />
        <TextBlock Margin="2" x:Name="Color" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" TextAlignment="Center" Text="Color">
            <TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
                <RotateTransform Angle="-90"/>
            </TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
        </TextBlock>

        <TextBlock Margin="2" x:Name="Brightness" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" TextAlignment="Center" Text="Brightness">
            <TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
                <RotateTransform Angle="-90"/>
            </TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
        </TextBlock>

        <Label Name="lblTest" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"/>

        <ListBox SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedObject}" 
                 PreviewMouseMove="ListBox_PreviewMouseMove"
                 PreviewMouseDown="ListBox_PreviewMouseDown"
                 Margin="10,10,10,10"
                 Grid.Column="1"
                 Grid.Row="1" PreviewMouseRightButtonDown="ListBox_PreviewMouseRightButtonDown">
            <ListBox.Template>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Border>
                        <Border.Background>
                            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,1" Opacity=".3">
                                <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0"/>
                                <GradientStop Color="LightGray" Offset="1"/>
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </Border.Background>

                        <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                            <Border>
                                <!-- This Border serves as a background and the VisualBrush used to paint its background serves as the "Snapping Grid" -->
                                <!-- The "Snapping" Actually occurs in the Node class (see Node.X and Node.Y properties), it has nothing to do with any UI Elements -->
                                <Border.Background>
                                    <VisualBrush TileMode="Tile"
                                    Viewport="0,0,20,20" ViewportUnits="Absolute" 
                                    Viewbox="0,0,20,20" ViewboxUnits="Absolute">
                                        <VisualBrush.Visual>
                                            <Rectangle Stroke="Darkgray" StrokeThickness="1" Height="24" Width="24"
                                        StrokeDashArray="5 3"/>
                                        </VisualBrush.Visual>
                                    </VisualBrush>
                                </Border.Background>
                                <ItemsPresenter/>
                            </Border>
                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </ListBox.Template>
            <ListBox.ItemsSource>
                <StaticResource ResourceKey="Col"/>
            </ListBox.ItemsSource>
            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <Canvas IsItemsHost="True" Background="#01FFFFFF" 
                            Height="{Binding AreaHeight}" Width="{Binding AreaWidth}"
                            VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding X}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Y}"/>
                    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource EmptyFocusVisualStyle}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                                <ContentPresenter x:Name="Content"/>
                                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                        <Setter TargetName="Content" Property="Effect">
                                            <Setter.Value>
                                                <DropShadowEffect Color="Gray" ShadowDepth="4" BlurRadius="10"/>
                                            </Setter.Value>
                                        </Setter>
                                    </Trigger>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsNew}" Value="True">
                                        <Setter Property="Opacity" Value=".5"/>
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>

</Grid>
```

So only "static" things are showing. Where are my "Nodes" (points) and "Connectors" (lines between points)? If any question please ask.

Comment: What on earth are you doing in the codebehind of the main window?  Your question isn't answerable because you haven't shown how you are databinding.  You can debug databinding issues, you know.  Go look at your output window at runtime.  You should start with a VERY simple prototype and move up from there.  You're trying to code way above your abilities.

Comment: Your DataContext objects UCData1..UCData6 does not have any connectors & nodes.